# Trouble in compiling GCC for LFS

Tags: linux, compiling

I wanted to compile the LFS and in GCC-13.2.0 Pass 1 but in the make step i encourted the error

```
done
make[4]: Leaving directory '/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-13.2.0/build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgcc'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-13.2.0/build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgcc'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-13.2.0/build'
make[2]: Entering directory '/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-13.2.0/build'
make[3]: Entering directory '/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-13.2.0/build'
rm -f stage_current
make[3]: Leaving directory '/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-13.2.0/build'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-13.2.0/build'
make[2]: Entering directory '/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-13.2.0/build'
Configuring stage 2 in ./intl
configure: loading cache ./config.cache
checking for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc...  /mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-13.2.0/build/./prev-gcc/xgcc -B/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-13.2.0/build/./prev-gcc/ -B/mnt/lfs/tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/mnt/lfs/tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/mnt/lfs/tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /mnt/lfs/tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include -isystem /mnt/lfs/tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/sys-include   -fno-checking
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-13.2.0/build/intl':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
make[2]: *** [Makefile:6551: configure-stage2-intl] Error 77
make[2]: Leaving directory '/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-13.2.0/build'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:21586: stage2-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-13.2.0/build'
make: *** [Makefile:1027: all] Error 2
```

I dont know what i missed out. I followed the LFS book. Anyone know answer?

Comment: Also i builded this from Debian minimal live cd with installed by me additional required libraries.

Comment: *"See `config.log' for more details"* Could we get these details ?

Comment: Yep. https://pastebin.com/BmPhfcDJ

Comment: So as it seems problems are 1 (line 92) : *gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-V'* and 2 (line 97) : *gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?* So I would retry after modifying lines 4396 and 4396 of the configure file. However this sounds strange to me.

Comment: A search suggests some possible solutions such as updating bash or installing the dev version of `libconfig`.

Comment: I did it but it doesnt [help](https://pastebin.com/AFWUsxXW), _still_ error

Comment: Are you trying to do this on a non-Linux partition, or one that is mounted noexec? What is the output of `findmnt -T /mnt/lfs/sources`?

Comment: `/mnt/lfs /dev/sda3 ext4   rw,relatime`

Comment: From your `config.log`: `Invocation command line was: $ ../configure --target= ` Target cannot be empty.  What is the output of `echo $LFS`?  Did you export it in section 2.6?